# performSegueWithIdentifier - Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject' to argument type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to pass some string data to a viewcontroller using `performSegueWithIdentifier`, but I get this error `Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?'. Type(Aka'Optional<AnyObject>.Type) to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'` 
Even if I use `sender:self`, it still does not work.
In the storyboard, the segue is made by dragging a segue from 1st to 2nd view controller.

```
@IBAction func resetPassword(sender: AnyObject) {



    FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordResetWithEmail(emailTextField.text!, completion: { (error) in

        var customError = error?.localizedDescription

            if error == nil {

                let noError = "Click on the link received in the email"
                self.emailTextField.text = ""
                self.emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: noError, attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()])
                self.customErroSent = noError

            performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSeventhToFifth", sender: AnyObject?)

                //self.resetButtonOutlet.hidden = true
              //  self.emailTextField.hidden = true

            } else {


                 self.emailTextField.text = ""
                self.emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:customError!, attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
            }
        })
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "fromSeventhToFifth" {
        if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? FifthViewController {
                    destViewController.label.text = customErroSent


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are passing the type `AnyObject?` - you need to pass an object,  You could say `performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSeventhToFifth", sender: self)` or since it accepts an optional even `performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSeventhToFifth", sender: nil)`

Comment: @Paulw11 if I pass `self`,  I get error "Implicit use of 'self' in closure". use 'self' to make capture semantics explicit.  if I pass `nil`, I get same error  as above. http://i.imgur.com/lSAnK8Y.png

Comment: You need to say `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSeventhToFifth", sender: self)`.  Note the use of `self` to qualify the method

Comment: @Paulw11 The error has disappeared. If you put your comment in the answer section I will vote it as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sender` parameter is of type `AnyObject?` - so you can supply any object reference or `nil`, but you can't put `AnyObject?` since that is a type, not an object.

The error you are getting when you make this change, **Implicit use of 'self' in closure**, refers to the invocation of the function `performSegueWithIdentifier`, not the `sender` argument.

Since you are calling the function from within a closure, Swift needs to ensure that the closure *captures* `self` i.e. prevents it from being deallocated while the closure still exists.

Outside the closure this capture isn't necessary as if the object that `self` refers to has been deallocated the code can't be executing (The code is part of `self`).

To capture `self`, simply refer to it inside the closure:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSeventhToFifth", sender: self)
```

or

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSeventhToFifth", sender: nil)
```

Comment: At least in Swift 4.0 it should be like: 
 self.prepare(segue: "showDetail", sender: self)
However, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Does it work to set the string without parameter name?

Comment: @Oleksandr - I am not sure what you are asking here.  Perhaps you need to ask a new question?

Answer (score 0):

`AnyObject?` is a optional type. You should set it nil or any instance of Class. For example:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSeventhToFifth", sender: nil)
performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSeventhToFifth", sender: slef)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.0, in TableView Project Template.
To declare:

```
// MARK: - Segues
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "fromSeventhToFifth" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

To call:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromSeventhToFifth", sender: self)
```